# Unable to expand customerid in salesoreders object - MS Dynamics 365 CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am trying to get list of orders for the customer whose email is equal to "customer_email@example.com".
For this I am executing

```
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.1/salesorders?$select=name,salesorderid&$expand=customerid($select=fullname,emailaddress1)&$filter=customerid/emailaddress1 eq 'customer_email@example.com'
```

while hitting this endpoint I'm getting bellow error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "0x0",
        "message": "Could not find a property named 'customerid' on type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.salesorder'."
    }
}
```

However `_customerid_value` is present in `salesorders`:

```json
{
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"4934903\"",
            "salesorderid": "030474b9-722c-ee11-bdf4-000d3a37ca8a",
            "_ownerid_value": "17bd0c02-d822-ee11-9cbe-00224809d59c",
            "shipto_contactname": "9999999999",
            "name": "test order",
            "emailaddress": "rahul@test.com",
            "ordernumber": "ORD-01000-F3Y9Y6",
            "_createdby_value": "17bd0c02-d822-ee11-9cbe-00224809d59c",
            "pricingerrorcode": 0,
            "totallineitemdiscountamount_base": 0.0000000000,
            "msdyn_iomreadonly": false,
            "_modifiedonbehalfby_value": "17bd0c02-d822-ee11-9cbe-00224809d59c",
            "statecode": 0,
            "msdyn_isreadytosync": false,
            "_customerid_value": "b258b768-722c-ee11-bdf4-000d3a37ca8a",
            "msdyn_isiomorder": false,
            "billto_line1": null,
            "shipto_telephone": null,
        }
```

Is there any way to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`customerid` is not a standard lookup (pointing to a single table) but a `customer` type, it can reference an account or a contact.

In Web API queries the navigation property is used when do some filtering, it can be the same as the lookup name but most of the time is not.

In your query you will need to change `customerid` to `customerid_account` (in both expand and filter points)

```
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.1/salesorders?$select=name,salesorderid&$expand=customerid_account($select=fullname,emailaddress1)&$filter=customerid_account/emailaddress1 eq 'customer_email@example.com'
```

If you need to generate other Web API queries you can use my tool [Dataverse REST Builder](https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB).